# cannot remove registry key based on data value search

Tags: powershell, registry

Working on a PowerShell script to remove registry key based on value search.

The goal of my script is to search from the root level for the data "values" then remove this key.

How can I search for value2 In the attached image ?

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force -Path hkcr:\
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only two registry drives available which you can query using the [Get-PSDrive](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113327) cmdlet:

```
Get-PSDrive -PSProvider Registry
```

*Result*:

```
Name Used (GB) Free (GB) Provider Root               CurrentLocation
---- --------- --------- -------- ----               ---------------
HKCU                     Registry HKEY_CURRENT_USER                 
HKLM                     Registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
```

However, you can create a registry drive for `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` using the [New-PSDrive](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113357) cmdlet:

```
New-PSDrive -PSProvider registry -Root HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT -Name HKCR
```

Now you are be able to search in there using the [Get-ChildItem](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113308) cmdlet:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force -Path hkcr:/*/OpenWithList
```

Comment: Thanks Jisaak. can you also provide the syntax to search and remove 'value2' in my example ?